# How to combine $in and $regex in mongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I am having a collection(say **Employees**), which is containing multiple documents. Each document has the following fields-

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "designation":"Product manager",
    "departmentID":['abpqr','def']
}
{
    "name":"David",
    "designation":"Senior s/w Engg",
    "departmentID":['abc','lmn']
}
{
    "name":"Mathew",
    "designation":"ODC head",
    "departmentID":['abpyz','xyz']
}
```

Now I want a mongo query to fetch the list of employees whose departmentID starts from 'abp'. It should be something like-
**db.Employees.find({departmentID: {$in: {$regex:'^abp'}}})**

Is it possible to fetch it by using a single query? If not then what is the alternate to get the result. I am using pymongo and the result I am expecting is-

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "designation":"Product manager",
    "departmentID":['abpqr','def']
},
{
    "name":"Mathew",
    "designation":"ODC head",
    "departmentID":['abpyz','xyz']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need $in operator in order to perform a query with only one condition.

```
db.Employees.find({departmentID:{$regex:'^abp'}})
```

It should works.

Comment: Thanks rebenfa! Its working now, and the reason I think $regex search inside list also without providing any extra effort.